# How to apply an eventListener to multiple elements with the same class and have each element respond independently

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I have a list of elements in my HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
```

And I was trying to make it so that every element I clicked on would log to the console the animal in the element.  This was my attempt:

```
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".zone");


selection.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection(element))
})


function pickSelection(animal) {
    console.log(animal.textContent)
}
```

But it was not returning anything when I clicked on any of the elements.  However, once I changed the eventListener to this, it started working:

```
selection.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => pickSelection(element))
})
```

Why does it work in the second version of the code and not the first?  In the first version, I thought I am passing the element argument to the pickSelection function by writing "pickSelection(element)", but apparently it only works if there is "() =>" in front of it, but what is the difference in this notation?  Thanks.

Comment: for event listner you should pass a method refrence.in second one you do it right.but in the first case you are passing undefined (what returns from the pickSelection method call) .first one should be `function(){pickSelection(element)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version you are executing the `pickSelection` function instead of passing its reference, the **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** expects a function reference as a callback when the particular event is *triggered*.

But since you passed return value of the `pickSelection` function which is `undefined` (as you are not returning anything from the `pickSelection` so by default it is returning `undefined`) it is not working.

In the second version you are actually passing the function reference to the `addEventListner`, which being a arrow function syntax.

This following would also work, by simply passing the reference `pickSelection`, but this time it will receive the **[`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)** object.

```js
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".zone");
selection.forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection)
})
function pickSelection(event) {
      //getting the event object from the callback, target refers to the current element clicked.
    console.log(event.target.textContent)
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks so much!  But another question I have, in the second version when it says: "() => pickSelection(element)", shouldn't the empty parentheses have a parameter inside of them?  Because in arrow function syntax doesn't () => mean the function takes no arguments?  But in the case of the pickSelection function, it does require one argument.

Comment: The arrow function `=>` is actually the *callback* which is called when the event happens, which in turn will call the `pickSelection` function and pass the `element` to it. It typically should take one argument which is the `event` object, like so: `(event) => pickSelection(element);` which is *optional*. But since you are already passing the `element` local variable to `pickSelection` it as working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection(element));
```

Is effectively this

```
const temp = pickSelection(element);
element.addEventListener('click', temp);
```

What you want is

```
element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection);
```

Do you see the difference?

In this version

```
element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection(element))
```

You called the function `pickSelection` and passed it `element`. Then passed whatever `pickSelection` returns to `element.addEventListener`

What you wanted / needed to do is pass the function itself to `element.addEventListener`

The reason this version works

```
selection.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => pickSelection(element))
})
```

is because you're passing an anonymous function to `element.addEventListener`. Those lines can be translated to this

```
function anonymousFn1(element) {
    function anonymousFn2() {
         pickSelection(element);
    }
    element.addEventListener('click', anonymousFn2);
}

selection.forEach(anonymousFn1);
```

Note that functionally there is another difference.

In this one

```
 element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection);
```

The click event passes an [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) to `pickSelection` whereas in the other one the variable `element` that was created when `forEach` called anonmousFn1 was "closed over" [(a closure was made)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) so when anonymousFn2 was call that `element` variable was use.

So to get the first one to work you really need this

```
function pickSelection(event) {
    const element = event.target;
    console.log(element.textContent);
}
```

Example:

```js
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".zone");

selection.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection);
});

function pickSelection(event) {
    element = event.target;
    console.log(element.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
    <div class="zone green"></div>
    <div class="zone red"></div>
    <div class="zone blue"></div>
    <div class="zone yellow"></div>
    <div class="zone purple"></div>
    <div class="zone brown"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: Registering a listener on each element is a bad practice. Use event delegation instead:

```js
document.querySelector(`.container`).addEventListener(`click`, ({target}) => {
  const el = target.closest(`.zone`);
  if (el) {
    console.log(el.textContent);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="zone green"></div>
  <div class="zone red"></div>
  <div class="zone blue"></div>
  <div class="zone yellow"></div>
  <div class="zone purple"></div>
  <div class="zone brown"></div>
  <div class="zone green"></div>
  <div class="zone red"></div>
  <div class="zone blue"></div>
  <div class="zone yellow"></div>
  <div class="zone purple"></div>
  <div class="zone brown"></div>
</div>
```